# angular form reset with form array clears the form array values

Tags: angular, angular-forms

i have a reactive form as follows

```
  editForm = new FormGroup({
    userId: new FormControl("", Validators.required),
    Reports: new FormArray([], Validators.required)
  });
```

i am pushing values into reports dynamically .
when i am resetting the values to the form as follows

```
this.editForm.reset({
userId:"some id",
Reports:[
{
reportId:1,
name:"report 1"
}
]
})
```

here is the what will be pushed into reports form array

```
new FormGroup({
    reportId: new FormControl(""),
    name: new FormControl(null, Validators.required)
  })
```

but it is not working. an empty array is binding to the reports. Any Thoughts?

Comment: How are you adding reports?

Comment: Depends on your form structure, right now it seems that you form array is an array of form controls. Is that right ?

Comment: it contains form groups.. updated the question with the structure

Comment: @ritaj i am pushing the form group into array.